# java serialization with different JVM version

Tags: java, object, serialization

I'm using a 3rd party tool of objectPlanet called easyChart to produce graphical chart. They provide a jar lib called Chart.jar and ChartServer.jar

I write an easyChart object on server side:

```
Chart chart = new BarChart();
... <create chart data here> ...
ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oStream = new ObjectOutputStream( bStream );
oStream.writeObject (chart);
byte[] byteVal = bStream.toByteArray();
String chartInString = Base64.encode(byteVal);
```

and read it back on client side:

```
byte[] readByte = Base64.decode(chartInString);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(readByte));
Chart chart = (Chart) ois.readObject();
```

It works fine when server and client has same JVM version. I realize that GenericChart implements Serialization (this class is inside the jar provided).

How I can overcome this matter since I can't modify their provided jar classes?

Much appreciate any reply.
Thank you!

Comment: Which problems do you experience?

Comment: lets say: server uses Java 6 update 27 when writing Chart object. I use 2 Client machine: 1st use Java 6 update 27, I can read the Chart object, 2nd use Java 7, I can't read the Chart object, it throws this exception: java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.swing.JComponent; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -1030230214076481435, local class serialVersionUID = 5670834184508236790

Answer (score 1):

> I can't read the Chart object, it throws this exception: java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.swing.JComponent; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -1030230214076481435, local class serialVersionUID = 5670834184508236790

Actually, this is not related to the JVM version but to the run time library. The class `javax.swing.JComponent` was changed in a way that makes the serial representation incompatible.

I am afraid, there is not much you can do about it apart from using the same version.

Comment: +1 - And the flip side is that if you need your persistence to work across multiple JVM versions, you are better of using a different mechanism; e.g. JSON or XML serialization or a database.

Comment: Or serialize the models instead of the Swing components themselves.

Answer (score 1):

There is a warning in the class Javadoc of every Swing class in existence that serialized versions will not be compatible with other JDK versions. So, don't serialize them. Serialize the models.

Comment: How do I serialize the model?